# In the goerli test network, the USDC token contract address of aavev3 loan is different from the USDC address of uniswapv3

Tags: web3js

I would like to ask, how to deal with the same token name but different token contract addresses during the aavev3 flash loan exchange. In the goerli test network, USDC has many token contracts, but I borrowed from aavev3 The USDC token is different from the USDC token address of uniswapv3. If I want to trade in USDC and WETH liquidity mining pools, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If aave v3 provides adding liquidity on testnet then you can add your choice of USDC and WETH to it . Goerli is a testnet so for testnet purposes it is not necessary that USDC (which is fake) should have same addresses on aave v3 as well.